# Ubuntu 20.04 boots to purple screen or black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

My ubuntu 20.04 boots to a purple screen / black screen with blinking cursor. I tried installing several nvidia-driver versions (515, 525, 530) but all seem to result in same problems with booting. I have tried installing them via the software centre, via the terminal, with a download of the driver via the website, but nothing seems to have the solution. Also booting in recovery mode does not always work.

I tried reinstalling ubuntu 20.04 but ran into the same issues again. Ubuntu 22.04 working perfectly fine (but unfortunately i need 20.04).

I have tried every solution regarding /etc/default/grub settings (nomodeset, quiet splash etc…) and also disabling wayland in gdm3.

I have a RTX A1000 Laptop GPU on a HP Zbook power G9

Right now I’m only able to get to a terminal using ctrl+alt+f6.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If 22.04 works and 20.04 does not it may be a kernel issue.

Comment: Does this help? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

In a way you're lucky that the latest LTS version works and the older LTS version doesn't work rather than the other way around. If there's a problem finding a Nvidia proprietary graphics driver that is compatible with your GPU then you're grinding your gears and stuck. Install Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtual machine like VirtualBox in Ubuntu 22.04 and the problem is solved.